# In jQuery, what is the colon vs the greater than sign?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between these two pieces of notation? I have an input field with the value 5 in it wrapped inside a class called `.deposit_amount`

```
$('.deposit_amount :input').val()
"5"
$('.deposit_amount>input').val()
"5"
```

This is my html:

```
<div class="deposit_field">
      <div class="deposit_toAddress" <label="">Deposit To:
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>

      <div class="deposit_amount" <label="">Deposit Amount:
        <input type="text" value="">
      </div>

      <input type="button" class="deposit_button" value="Deposit">
    </div>
```

Comment: `"5"` is wrong. There is nothing in jquery like this

Comment: Well, tha'ts the value in my input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` selector is a direct-child selector, much like CSS. That is, it only selects an element that is a direct children of `'.deposit_amount'`, in your case.

You can read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

The `:input` selector basically matches any form control within the parent div.

You can also read more about that here: https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 3):

It's not really jQuery per se, these are [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), but the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) one is a jQuery addition.

- `.desposit_amount :input` matches any `input` or `select` or `textarea` that's a descendant (child or child of child or...) of an element with the `desposit_amount` class. The space without anything else in it is a *descendant combinator* (see CSS spec linked above).
- `.desposit_amount>input` matches any `input` (but not `select` or `textarea`) that's a *direct child* of an element with the `desposit_amount` class. The `>` is a *child combinator* (see CSS spec linked above).

The only jQuery-specific part is the `:input` pseudo-selector jQuery adds.